# Determine how Django formats timezones

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-timezone

I have a Django 1.6 project with the following relevant settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
TIME_FORMAT = 'Hi'
DATE_FORMAT = 'Y M d'
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%s %s e' % (DATE_FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT)
USE_TZ = True
USE_L10N = False
```

I have an object called `session` with a datetime field called `start`.

```
>>> session.start
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 7, 15, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I want to display that datetime in the project's local timezone,

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.localtime(session.start)
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 7, 8, 0, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone>)
```

So far so good. Now I want that local datetime to be displayed as a unicode string.

```
>>> str(timezone.localtime(session.start))
'2014-06-07 08:00:00-07:00'
```

My problem is that, instead of `-07:00` I want the timezone to be displayed as `PDT`. How can I change this?

Ideally I just want to convert the local datetime to a unicode string using the format specified in `DATETIME_FORMAT`. The [documentation for date format strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) says that `e` "could be in any format, or might return an empty string, depending on the datetime" but it does not suggest how I might specify what format I want.

Comment: if you scroll down it certainly explains how to use the date with the appropriate format.

Comment: Also the link you provide is related to template filters / tags, my comment assumes you want to format that for a template. If not be more specific (regarding where you want the formatting to appear).

Comment: I want to format it outside of a template. It will be done in a view, but I would like to know how to do it just in the shell. I want to do this using the previously defined `DATETIME_FORMAT` so that the end result is the same as it would appear if it was in a template, without having to define another formatting string in my code.

Comment: Try this:
`time = datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 7, 8, 0, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone>)`
`time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z')`